# making a loding screen but all it says is 12345678910

Tags: batch-file

so i made a loading screen but it doesnt work and i cant figure it out heres the code:

```
@echo off
:start
set a=10
pause
set 1=_
set 2=_
set 3=_
set 4=_
set 5=_
set 6=_
set 7=_
set 8=_
set 9=_
set 10=_
:b
cls
echo %a%
if %a%==10 goto 1
if %a%==20 goto 2
if %a%==30 goto 3
if %a%==40 goto 4
if %a%==50 goto 5
if %a%==60 goto 6
if %a%==70 goto 7
if %a%==80 goto 8
if %a%==90 goto 9
if %a%==100 goto 10
:1
set 1=#
goto echo
:2
set 2=#
goto echo
:3
set 3=#
goto echo
:4
set 4=#
goto echo
:5
set 5=#
goto echo
:6
set 6=#
goto echo
:7
set 7=#
goto echo
:8
set 8=#
goto echo
:9
set 9=#
goto echo
:10
set 10=#
goto echo
:echo
echo %1% %2% %3% %4% %5% %6% %7% %8% %9% %10%
set /a a+=10
TIMEOUT 1 >null
cls
goto b
```

so if anyone figures it out im very thank ful for answers i just cant understand why it would not work....

thanks :)

Comment: and what is the loding screen supposed to do?

Comment: "it doesnt work" is not a question.

Comment: Avoid using keywords as goto markers, such as "echo".

Answer (score 2):

`%n` where n is a single digit is interpreted by batch to mean 'this parameter number to the batch or procedure'.

Hence, echo `%n%` does nt work as you expect.

Futhermore, `echo` is a keyword and hence a poor choice for a label.

And the device is `nul`, not `null`. You'll find that you have created a file called `null` from this code.

Answer (score 0):

OK im not quite sure what's wrong but if you want a relay good looking loading screen use this http://www.battoexeconverter.com/ It allows you to compile your bat file to an exe. but more to the point it has some advanced commands that will allow you to make a good loading screen. see the sample codes when you install it. They are in a tab at the top.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, the main problem with your code is that a variable name can not start with digit, because `%digit-restOfName%` will always be expanded as `%digit`=Batch file parameter, followed by `-restOfName...`. However, I would like to present you some other points:

- When several lines of code are repeated varying just a numeric value (or a series of any given values), you may "compress" the lines in just one line placed into a `for` command that will execute it with each one of the values.
- Several variables that have the same name, but a varying number ("*subscript*") comprises an [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) that may also be managed via a `for` command.
- You may use the value of a variable (or substring part) at *any place* in a Batch program, excepting a label. This feature may be used to write much shorter code via "tricks"; for example: `goto %labelVar%`.

The Batch file below is your original code modified accordingly to these ideas:

```
@echo off
:start
set a=10
pause
for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do set v%%i=_
:b
cls
echo %a%
set v%a:~0,-1%=#
echo %v1% %v2% %v3% %v4% %v5% %v6% %v7% %v8% %v9% %v10%
set /a a+=10
TIMEOUT 1 >nul
cls
goto b
```